# Catch String [] keys of Application.Resources

Tags: java

I am with the following problem.
In my Application Resources, I own:

```
conf.bol.caminho.padrao = "padrao.jsp"
```

So I wanted to do the following:
I want to load into a String key (conf.bol.caminho.padrao)

example:

```
String text = "conf.bol.caminho.padrao";
System.out.println(text);
```

Result:

```
padrao.jsp
```

How to do it?

Comment: Are you using Spring, or property files, or ... ?

Comment: You need to load the properties file somewhere. Are you doing this?

Comment: You need to obtain the resource, for example using `Properties` object

Comment: Code example? I need it! I'm use java 5

Comment: Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("defaultProperties");
defaultProps.load(in);
in.close();